# Python code to access a website that uses SSO (SAML)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

My company recently purchased the Cisco webex online meeting service. I am exploring its API capability. The webex web portal does SSO with our ADFS server. I am wondering how to use python to write a script to support this type of authentication as a client (just like when I open my Chrome browser and do the login). I googled but all came back was how to make a Service Provider (SP) to do SSO... My request is not that complicated at all... Could you please provide some direction? A sample code is much appreciated! Thank you.